# Read content of several txt files into python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, supervised-learning

I have two folders, each folder contains words in various .txt files, one folder is named 'good' while the other is named 'bad', I want to write a python script that will import all the data into a dataframe and the dataframe will have 'Id' column, 'word' column and 'label' column.
The label column will either be 'good' or 'bad' based on the folder name.

I have written the following python script, but i seem to be having issues with file encoding type, I have installed the 'cahrdet' library to detect the file encoding type but i still get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 1400: illegal multibyte sequence
```

```
good_path = "myfolder/good"
bad_path = "myfolder/bad"


ids = []
words = []
labels = []


for filename in os.listdir(good_path):
    with open(os.path.join(good_path, filename), "rb") as f:
        result = chardet.detect(f.read())
        encoding = result["encoding"]
    with open(os.path.join(good_path, filename), "r", encoding=encoding) as f:
        word_content = f.read()
        ids.append(filename)
        words.append(word_content)
        labels.append("good")


for filename in os.listdir(bad_path):
    with open(os.path.join(bad_path, filename), "rb") as f:
        result = chardet.detect(f.read())
        encoding = result["encoding"]
    with open(os.path.join(bad_path, filename), "r", encoding=encoding) as f:
        word_content = f.read()
        ids.append(filename)
        words.append(word_content)
        labels.append("bad")

# Create a dataframe from the lists
df = pd.DataFrame({"Id": ids, "words": words, "label": labels})
```

Comment: Where have these text files come from? Why isn't the encoding known beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the encoding to utf-8 directly

python3 is fully supported

```py
for filename in os.listdir(good_path):
    with open(os.path.join(good_path, filename), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        word_content = f.read()
        ids.append(filename)
        words.append(word_content)
        labels.append("good")


for filename in os.listdir(bad_path):
    with open(os.path.join(bad_path, filename), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        word_content = f.read()
        ids.append(filename)
        words.append(word_content)
        labels.append("bad")
```

Comment: thanks @chrisfang I did, but I got this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 1054: invalid start byte

Comment: @highclef  you get the encoding from chardet
But that's not necessarily true.    `detect` logic ->    createed  `UniversalDetector` object and `feed` it.
'feed' determines that the header protocol matches the common utf family,
If not, the data is then re matched, of course, the encoding type may be empty.

Comment: @highclef   `errors='ignore'` if we want to ensure that the program is readable when it is executing properly.
Of course, this is not the best way
The best way or need to determine your txt file data source, your txt data format is how to save the original

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I was able to filter out the text files with (character) the wrong encoding and exclude them with a try-except block to catch the UnicodeDecodeError exception.